# HWND abc = 0x100; This does not work, and I understand why. How to do it then?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a HWND variable that I want to point to an hardcoded value, just for testing purposes. I guess that HWND is a typedef of (int*) so that is causing some kind of indirection. What should the correct code be like?

Comment: By does not work do you mean does not compile or fails to execute?

Answer (score 7):

```
HWND abc = (HWND)(0x100);
```

Anyway, bad idea, but you already know that.

Comment: reintrepret_cast<HWND>(0x100): We are not lowly C programmers :-)

Comment: "Lowly", pshaw! We prefer "terse and surly".

Answer (score 5):

You can do:    `HWND hWnd = reintrepret_cast<HWND>(0x100);` . Use explicit cast so that it is easy to find in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hard code an HWND value.  At best, it would not refer to an existing window.  At worst, it would refer to some random window in the system.

**Edit:** To be clear, any tests you run using the hardcoded value will be meaningless.  Your program uses that HWND for *something*.  As soon as it passes the hardcoded HWND to an API function, either that function will fail (best case) or it will cause random, unpredictable effects in random processes (worst case).